# Cakephp twitter api 1.1 error HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Length: 0 Connection: close

Tags: twitter, cakephp-2.3

I have problem in using twitter API 1.1 with cakephp.
When I call https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json to search tweet the response always returns HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Length: 0 Connection: close.

### I check request raw of this request:

```
GET /1.1/search/tweets.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: CakePHP
Authorization: 
OAuth oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_token="822896990-Eazz9XQVzZ2I9l53pRhbGKxsxxxxxxxxxxx",
oauth_consumer_key="T1rqat2i3nV30xxxxxxxx",
oauth_nonce="652bbdc4c9e2f91a16c7f166xxxxxxxx",
oauth_timestamp="1380334675",
oauth_signature="4HYs4uPTxOOGtA%2F6uHxxxxxxxxxxx"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 9

q=datnoid
```

---

But when I call api: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/$id.'.json'
It return result OK.

### The request raw:

```
GET /1.1/statuses/show/382331096781692928.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: CakePHP
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_token="822896990-Eazz9XQVzZ2I9l53pRhbGKxsHi2Yxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
oauth_consumer_key="T1rqat2i3nV30xxxxxxxxxx",
oauth_nonce="78a8b446ea3c9cba1ff0exxxxxxxxxx",
oauth_timestamp="1380334472",
oauth_signature="hTKPIvUh6F9XxCxhgClQjxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

---

The only different between two request is the first one has parameter search [q=datnoid] and the second one has no parameter at all!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, The twitter component I use has wrong code.
It pass param for request[body] for all get/post method.